# Getting "can't write unknown attribute" when trying to save has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many

I”m using Rails 5.  I have two models that relate to one another …

```
class Scenario < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :grading_rubric, optional: true
  has_many :confidential_memo
  has_many :roles

  attr_accessor :roles_str
end
```

and

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :scenario
end
```

I have this table that relates the two …

```
sims=> \d scenario_roles
                                  Table "public.scenario_roles"
   Column    |            Type             |                          Modifiers                          
-------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                     | not null default nextval('scenario_roles_id_seq'::regclass)
 scenario_id | integer                     | 
 role_id     | integer                     | 
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

However, when I try and create and save things in my controller, I’m having a problem.  Here’s what I’m doing

```
  def create
    @scenario = Scenario.new(scenario_params)
    # Define the roles for this scenario
    role_names = @scenario.roles_str.split("\n")
    roles = []
    role_names.each do |role|
      role_obj = Role.new({:name => role, :scenario => @scenario})
      if role_obj.save!
        roles.push(role_obj)
      end
    end
    @scenario.roles = roles
    respond_to do |format|
      if @scenario.save
```

I’m getting the error, “can't write unknown attribute `scenario_id`” on the line “role_obj = Role.new({:name => role, :scenario => @scenario})”.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you are using a join table (scenario_roles), that means you want to have a many-to-many relationship between Scenarios and Roles. In that case, your ScenarioRole model should have a belongs_to for Scenario and Role and then Scenario and Role would have a has_many relationship to the join table.

Comment: So Scenario and Role would have "has_many :scenario_roles"?

Comment: yup. in your example, you are creating a Role and instantly trying to associate it to a Scenario. then later in the code, you try to associate an array of Roles to a Scenario. you should only make that association once.